# App TranSport security, allow arbitrary load not working after upgrade to IOS 10.1

Tags: ios, ios10, app-transport-security

I have an app that works fine in ios 9 and 10.0 (I have add the App Transport Security blocking with “Allow Arbitrary Loads = YES” to my info.plist. But after upgrade to 10.1 and Xcode 8.1 there seem to be a problem with the App Transport Security. I can not connect to server. My server only support up to TLS 1.1

Showing this error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1022 "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection.
```

May be IOS 10.1 ignore the .plist info. (Note that on 9.3 till 10.0 it is still working fine).

My .plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>SingPost</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.8.7</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1540614276180366</string>
            </array>
            <key>Item 0</key>
            <string>fb1540614276180366</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.8.7</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1540614276180366</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Singpost</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>prdesb1.singpost.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>mobile.singpost.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>    </string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>    </string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses photos</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>OpenSans-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Semibold.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-Light.ttf</string>
        <string>OpenSans-LightItalic.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I fix my add exeptiondomain but have this error in console

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) –
```

Edit from suggestion. I change my plist to

```
<key>mobile.singpost.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <key>mysam.sg</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
```

Comment: What version of Xcode were you building with before 8.1?  Can you show your Info.plist settings?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8. I'm fixing it by adding Exeption Domains. but in the console I get this error: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.1. ios 10.1. I'm fixing it by adding Exeption Domains. but in the console I get this error: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Comment: Which URL is is specifically compaining about?  Use the nscurl command to check what about the url is failing the SSL handshake: `nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.domain.com`.  My guess is that is is less about not satisfying the ATS requirements, but more about a certificate trust issue.  Disabling ATS does not allow you to connect to secure web servers where the cert has problems.  Disabling ATS will, however, allow you to connect to servers using SSL that does not use the latest versions / standards / key strength.  It doesn't answer how this was able to work before though.

Comment: Also, are you accessing these resources in a UIWebView? Through an NSUrlConnection?

Comment: Hi this is my cur log: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16APWQippnSNr0_BWqDQd36kzRA6IpbsLSHKIt0xgEFY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm connect using URLSession (AFNetworking 3)

Comment: Your exception for that domain seems correct.  Are you sure that is the server you are receiving the error for?

Comment: Hi Yes, we use that server used. I constantly get this error NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) –

Comment: And you are sure the exact same build is running on the iOS 10.0 devices as the 10.1?  There is something else at play here because ATS exceptions are still working properly on our 10.1 devices.  We have different exceptions, though.  I would open a radar with Apple.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By specifying `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent`, you are overriding `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` on iOS 10.

> In iOS 10 and later, and macOS 10.12 and later, **the value of [the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`] key is ignored** if any of the following keys are present in your app’s Info.plist file:
>
> - NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia
> - NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent
> - NSAllowsLocalNetworking

*Source: [App Transport Security dictionary primary keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW34) (Apple)*

Additionally, the `NSExceptionDomain` dictionaries you have provided don't seem to match the [current documented format](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35). Specifically, the keys don't match:

- `NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` should be **`NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads`**
- `NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion` should be **`NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion`**
- `NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` should be **`NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy`**

Comment: Thanks a lot. I change my .plist to edit question. Should that be ok or we have to incude other plist for server connection? (My server only support TLS 1.1)